# Emails Delayed for hours at server

Tags: windows-server-2003, email

I manage a network where we utilize Gmail as our email provider and Bluehost as our domain host. Recently we have been experiencing an issue where a few emails are delayed for several hours. After looking up the message headers I found that they are hanging for about 6 hours at one of our local servers before being delivered. However, that server is not our domain controller, and really, as far as I can tell, shouldn't be needed by the affected users. We use that server to run school management software (ACS Procare). I've pinged the server from that workstation and others and received a quick response. The server in question is a windows 2003 server, and the workstations are a mix of apple and microsoft workstations (windows 7 and OSX 10.8).

I should also mention that when I went to access the problem server (after the delays had occurred) there was an error message that ccmsetup.exe had failed, and that there was a problem with the ACS backup procedure.

Any ideas why the emails would be going to that server in the first place?

And any ideas what the cause for an intermittent delay like that?

Thanks

Comment: I doubt that ccmsetup.exe or the ACS backup is related to the issue with the email delays.

Comment: If you're using email for time-sensitive information delivery, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: Emails don't "hang up" at servers that aren't email servers, so give us some more detail on the server that these emails are "hanging" on and why they would be there in the first place. Emails also don't "hang up" on Domain Controllers unless the DC is also an email server, which is strongly discouraged.

Answer (score 2):

Gmail is not intended as a server-side e-mail provider. They have fairly strict rate limits on outgoing e-mails and I'd guess you're hitting them. You need a legitimate e-mail service provider like Mandrill, SendGrid, AmazonSES, etc. to send your server's e-mails.

Comment: This is Google Apps, not Gmail, and the emails having issues are internal emails rather than emails being sent out.

Comment: Gmail has similar limits. If you're rate limited, your internal server is going to hang on to them and reattempt delivery.

Comment: I guess one of the questions is, why is it even touching this server? This server isn't an email server.

Comment: If it's sending e-mails, it likely has a local MTA for queueing.